# Android & Servers - What server software can I use, I'm at a loss

Tags: android, installation, communication

I am going to create a simple application that sends a string to a server, my problem is I have no idea what technology to use.

For example, with some research I can implement a client in Android. But for the server - that I wish to host on my home laptop, I am confused about which route to take.

I have looked into XMPP servers - but they are for instant messaging. Can anyone recommend some server software that I might be able to use - or can I ever write my own server?

Answer (score 3):

To just send a string to the server, a simple web page with a cgi script can be enough. You should better describe the use case you are thinking of. Otherwise there is a huge wealth of technologies to choose from.

Comment: Hi Heiko, the use case is really simple, I would ideally like to populate an XML doc from string values held in a sqlite database, and send this to a server. For example, a shopping list - any ideas what would be most suited for this?

Comment: A REST-ful API could help you here. I think Ruby on Rails has tooling to easily do the server side. Also (as the Android-app is in Java), Java EE 6 with JAX-RS could do the job. And again just a cgi script in perl / shell ... I think on the server side just do whatever is fastest for you to get started.

Comment: Heiko, yes I think I am going to go for the minimalist approach and write a Java Server , using an ObjectOutputStream between the application and server. I have now decided I will serialize the applications database and send it across the network, where it can then be inspected.